# Apache clears Flask session when it redirects to a new page

Tags: apache, flask, session-cookies

I am running a web interface based on a Flask app. I use the module `session` from flask to save the user ID and other arguments used later on in the sub-pages of the interface.

I had the same issue locally but setting `session.modified = True` solved it for me.

Now, the web app works locally. But, once I deployed it on EC2 instance using an Apache server, the session loses all it arguments when I redirect to the second page, and I get **500: Internal Server Error.**

This is snippet code of my Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify, session, abort
import os, sys, json
import boto3
import conf.credentials as conf
import secrets

#---- SET UP CONNECTIONS ----#
secret = secrets.token_urlsafe(32) 
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.secret_key = secret


@app.route('/<qualtrics_data>')
def index(qualtrics_data):
    appliance = request.args.get('appliance')
    ID = request.args.get('ID')
  
    session["appliance"] = appliance
    session["ID"] = ID
  
    session.modified = True

    return render_template("index.html")
```

The error raises here when I attempt to retrieve the data from session:

```
@app.route('/experiment_0')
def experiment_0():
    appliance = session["appliance"]
```

And this is the error message in the error log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5qHP.png)

Any suggestion could be helpful -- Thanks :))

Comment: If you found the answer yourself then [answer your question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Don't edit the answer into the question or use the word "Solved" in the question title.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is my first post here.. I will fix it :) thank  you for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret key of the flask app should be fixed

```
#secret = secrets.token_urlsafe(32) 
secret = "some fixed string"
```

This fixed it for me